# Markdown code block with user-input bolded

Tags: markdown

We are using Markdown for all our labs and study modules and everything works great. We are using Typora for all the editing since it provides (non-technical) users with a quick way to view their output in human-readable format, i.e., WYSIWYG.
However, management has expressed their desire for some customization of the Markdown files so it more accurately reflects the code. In other words, they want user-input to be bolded in the fenced code. Also, they wanted a ToC that when converted to PDF format would be clickable.

In response to this, I started using Eisvogel. It does pretty much everything needed except for bolded code font. I was able to get some basic bolding by using the formula:

```bash
lab@desktop:~$ ssh lab@172.25.11.3
lab@172.25.11.3's password:
[lab@centos1 ~]$
```

[bolded text in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naaTt.png)

However, they still would like a colored background, though this is not required.

Ideally, they would like some thing O'Reilly-esque, like the following:

[O'Reilly bolded code and then Courier regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL0De.png)

I have also included some LaTeX code at the beginning of the first Lab file, which does provide a lot of functionality. And, I have added additional text to the Eisvogel document so I can have multi-colored text boxes.

Any suggestions for bolding code font?

I have read through all the posts here, and I recognize Markdown takes code and will not do anything else with it. However, I have done something similar using LaTeX, but aside from moving everyone to LaTeX (which would not go over well with the ndev folks), was wondering if there was a way to incorporate the TeX code into Markdown like I have done with the test labs.

This is my `build.sh` file:

```
pandoc  --toc \
    --toc-depth 2 \
        "T1.md" \
        -s -o "Test_v23.pdf" \
        --from markdown \
        --filter=pandoc-latex-environment \
        --template "eisvogel.tex" \
        --listings
```

I attempted to add the contents of my T1.md file and the custom items from my eisvogel.tex file, but it looked like Spam, which given the length of this post, probably now is...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're only targetting PDF output? if so, you can include some raw TeX... e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63845/boldface-and-subscripts-in-verbatim-mode Once you've something working in TeX, you can write a [pandoc lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to convert the markdown (e.g. [spans](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans)) to the rquired raw tex.

Comment: That’s good to know. I will give that a try later today. Much appreciated.